# Deserialize XML attribute that contains an XML String

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm working with a third-party web API that returns to me some XML which has an attribute containing some serialized XML.

I'd like to deserialize this response to a POJO using Jackson, but I can't seem to find how to annotate my classes to make this work.

Here's a dummy example matching the received response structure, with the stringified XML in the `nested` attribute:

```xml
<MainElement
  foo="Bar"
  nested="&lt;nested baz=&quot;value&quot; /&gt;"
><MainElement/>
```

The classes I defined would then look like this:

```java
// Imports

@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class MainElement {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String foo;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private Nested nested;

  // Getters & Setters
}
```

```java
// Imports

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "nested")
public class Nested {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String baz;

  // Getters & Setters
}
```

Alas, this configuration doesn't seem to work and raises a `MismatchedInputException` from Jackson which, in essence, states the following:

```
Cannot construct instance of `com.example.Nested` (although at least one Creator exists):
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('<nested baz="value" />')
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That is not going to be as easy as you want, because XML should not be nested like this. You should contact whoever built that third-party API and recommend they write a new version that properly nests XML.

Comment: Well... I was kind of expecting this to not be easy, anyway ; I'm not an expert on XML, but this kind of nesting seemed shaddy even to me.
As for asking the developer to implement proper XML, I could do that (and I probably will), but the change won't happen anytime soon (if at all). In the meantime, I need to handle this in my app. At the very least, I can leave the field as a `String`, and use the `XmlMapper` to decode it on the fly as needed.

Comment: You will probably need to write a custom deserializer for the property, that accepts the string input and then deserializes that content separately.